# Ajax: Populate <div> with content from a post's ID not working - duplicating current page html instead

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, ajax, jquery, post-meta

Ok guys and gals, I'm losing my mind here...

I am looking to append the content and a custom field of a post to a div on page. The ID of the content and custom field is defined by a data attribute on a link to be selected by the user.

Issue is the output of the function called by ajax is not being populated - instead the entire html of the current page is being duplicated instead.

**This is the html of the selectors and output div on the page...**

```
<p><a class="funnel-direction" data-funnel-id="123" href="#">Option One</a> <a class="funnel-direction" data-funnel-id="456" href="#">Option Two</a></p>

<div id="result"></div> <!-- whole page gets duplicated in here - wtf? -->
```

**This is enqueuing my script for the ajax call**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_ajax_scripts' );

function add_ajax_scripts() {

   wp_enqueue_script( 'funnel-ajax', DNA_FU . 'js/funnel-ajax.js', array(), '1.0.0', true ); // working fine

   wp_localize_script( 'funnel-ajax', 'funnel_ajax', array(
    'ajaxurl'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'ajaxnonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'ajax_post_validation' )
  ));

}
```

**This is the function being called by ajax - it is this content I want to populate in `<div id="result"></div>`.**

```
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_dna_add_funnel_part', 'dna_add_funnel_part' );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_dna_add_funnel_part', 'dna_add_funnel_part' );

function dna_add_funnel_part() {

  $id       = $_POST['postid'];
  $meta     = get_post_meta($id, 'dna_funnel_info', true);

  $content  = apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $id));
  $data     = !empty($meta) ?  '<p>' . $meta . '</p>' : '';
  
  echo $content . $data;

  wp_die();

}
```

**finally, here is my ajax .js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('a.funnel-direction').on( 'click', function(e) {
  
    e.preventDefault();

    var postid = $(this).attr('data-funnel-id');

    console.log(postid); // working

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: funnel_ajax.ajax_url,
      data: {
        action: 'dna_add_funnel_part',
        postid: postid,
      },
      success: function(data) {

        // console.log(data);

        $('#result').html(data); // This populates the entire html of the current
                                 // page - it should only popualte the output of 
                                 // the dna_add_funnel_part() wordpress function
      },
      fail: {
        // to do ...
      }
    });

    return false; 

  });

});
```

Have looked over and over this can can't spot anything hope fully y'all can spot it!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "entire html of the current page"? Do you mean everything including the site header, footer, sidebars etc? Or do you mean the entire content of the page as entered in _Pages > All Pages > Edit_? I notice your AJAX callback is returning the `post_content`. Is that what you mean? Or is result just supposed to contain the `dna_funnel_info` meta?

Comment: Hi Jacob - yes, the entire html header, footer, etc (even the <head>)

Comment: Jacob - and yes the content and `dna_funnel_info` meta. So is the user clicked the button with `data-funnel-id="123"` then I want to populate with the both the content and metafield of post ID 123 

Comment: This full HTML page, what is it the page of? The current post? The desired post? A 404? Is there a reason you haven't implemented this as a simple `the_content`PHP filter server side? What was the reason for using the older admin ajax API instead of making an AJAX request to the posts rest endpoint at `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/idgoeshere`?

Comment: @TomJNowell - yes, the entire html of the current (not desired) post. I’m not sure what you mean by a server-side filter?   The reason behind this method is because the content needs to be served depending on a user’s choice as they progress through the page - we could do this over multiple pages but I wanted to do this without the need of a page refresh.

The older Ajax API is being used for two reasons

1) I am simply more familiar with it (normally!)

2 This functionality is to be used onto another site for the client - one which has the REST API disabled for security purposes

Comment: If your goal is to put the content of a specific post at the end of other posts, then why not filter `the_content` in PHP and add it to the end there? Why go through all the faff and effort of an AJAX call and javascript? Also the REST API is arguably more secure than admin-ajax, the core REST API endpoints are battle hardened and written by some of the most experienced devs in the WP ecosystem. You and I on the other hand probably don't have that experience ourselves. I can easily see several issues in the code you have already, e.g. not sanitising the ID, assuming the ID is for a post, etc

Comment: Also, turning off the REST API cripples OEmbeds, breaks the block editor, and a lot of other compatibility issues with plugins. Disabling it is not a good idea. Even if you use the classic editor, plugins such as Yoast rely on custom REST API endpoints. Also, if you had used `register_post_meta` to register `dna_funnel_info` then it would be included in the official post endpoint, and you wouldn't need to write a custom endpoint, you could even reuse the example code in the docs

Comment: As for your problem, it's very unlikely that the code in your question is the cause, but rather that code elsewhere is the problem, either because it is loading entire templates ad has't accounted for AJAX endpoints, or it's misused the `the_content` filter to load a top level template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, you made a really, really silly typo:

```
'ajaxurl'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
.....
url: funnel_ajax.ajax_url,
```

`ajaxurl` != `ajax_url`. So your Admin AJAX request is not returning a full HTML page. You're not even hitting the AJAX file!

**However, this is still completely the wrong way to go about this**

---

I was going to suggest that you instead use the REST API which is much easier and foolproof, and to write a custom endpoint using `register_rest_route` to give you a pretty URL such as `example.com/wp-json/richerimage/v1/dnafunnel`, but you don't need to.

In fact, you don't even need an AJAX handler or an endpoint. Just use the one that core gives you.

First, register the post meta so it appears in the REST API responses:

PHP:

```php
$args = array(
    'type' => 'string',
    'description' => 'DNA Funnel Info thing',
    'single' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
);
register_post_meta( 'post', 'dna_funnel_info', $args );
```

Then retrieve the desired post, e.g. `example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/post/123` where 123 is the ID of the post you wanted. The JSON response will contain the content in its fully rendered form, title, taxonomies, etc, including a meta section with all the meta keys you registered.

If your post ID is for a CPT, make sure `show_in_rest` is set to true when it's registered, and replace `/post/` with the relevant endpoint for that CPT

Or better yet, use PHP:

```php
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {
    // append post 123's content to the end
    return $content . get_the_content( '', '', 123 );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you Tom - it was the typo!! 

Agree with REST API route - reason not pursuing this method is function needs to be replicated on a site which has the API disabled due to security

Thanks again 

Comment: @richerimage why would anybody disable the REST API for security reasons? My understanding is that this harms not helps the site, and that very few people do this ( as it breaks lots of things ), and it would be more secure than the AJAX endpoint in your question. Additionally, you said this AJAX call is made from a different site, hence why it isn't done in PHP, so it doesn't matter if that site has a REST API or not, because it's talking to a 3rd party. IMO you're well within your rights to say those sites aren't supported